# looking up value starting with specific number in excel

Tags: excel, lookup

i have a look up request but starting with a tabled range

so for example the below is the lookup values

```
0662
0680
1242
1347
```

the criteria is such that the i want to list the values starting with the given above table so below is the list i want to sort

```
066245662146
066245845663
066245845664
124254899466
124254489966
124258848999
068024588644
068058996466
```

the first 4 digits are to be looked up and need to list the number in the range.

so for 0662 , all the numbers starting with 0662 will be populated.

Comment: Looks like all those values are valid. Either way, what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: excel 2019 is what i am using, but i have to make file to work on 2016 as well

Answer (score 0):

1-add 1 as a flag to the yoour lookup values
2-apply left formula to the your data column to split first 4 digit for each numbers.
3-app vlookup or index+match or easiest one, sumifs to sum flags according to the lookup values which are located in the splitted column.
4-filter columns with numbers greater than 0.
5-filtered valeus will come up with your expected lookup numbers.

Comment: Only issue with this is that some numbers are starting with zero

Comment: you can add a letter to each data like ="A"&  then A0662 will be shown rather than 662